# Split polygon by regard of distance to other shapefile

Tags: qgis, polygon, splitting

Is there some function that use distance to point/polyline layer to split a polygon layer

In Sweden the law says that undivided water belongs to the nearest property so sometimes I need to calculate what parts of a lake that belong to which real estate. Now I have to do it in several steps but I wonder if there are any function that I can use. I divide the beach-line into separate polylines (per real estate) but can I split the lake-polygon I separate polygons in regard of nearest polyline.

I have the same problem sometimes when calculate in forest when I have to divide the forestland in regard of gathering point for the logging but then I use a point layer to divide the polygon calculate where

Now I use multiple buffer zones then manually split the polygon "along the fold" of the buffers

Edit:
Added two pictures so you maybe understand better

Exempel, red lines are divided water and I added green on undivided water
[image]

I used point grid and connected to nearest polyline-feature then I have to manually split along the color
[image]

Comment: Did you try [Voronoi's Polygon](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=delaunay#voronoi-polygons) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can :

1. create [centroids](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=delaunay#centroids) of your buldings
2. use [Voronoi Polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=delaunay#voronoi-polygons) with those centroids
3. [clipped](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html?highlight=clip#clip) the polygons with the water surface

If you also need the beach line, you can create the [boundary](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=delaunay#boundary) of your water surfaces and clip it with the Voronoi Polygon aswell.

You can also create centroids for line features.

Example:

Buildings are in purple, red and dark blue. Water surfaces are represented in light blue.
[image]

Centroid creation:
[image]

Voronoi Polygon creation:
[image]

Voronoi Polygon clipped by water surface (Water surfaces are divided depending on the closest building):
[image]